# I can't add strings together in a for loop

Tags: python

My python code that was supposed to take a string from the user and create a new string from even numbered lettes of the string that the user entered isn't working.

```
q = ("")
x = str(input("Bir string giriniz: "))
if len(x) != 0 :
    for i in range(len(x)) :
        if (i%2==0) :
            (q + x[i]) == q
print(q)
```

Comment: Please add all the text that doesn't fit in the title in the body of the question instead.

Comment: By the way, it can be simply `print(x[::2])`

Answer (score 1):

```
q = ""
x = input("Please enter string:")
for index, letter in enumerate(x):
    if index % 2 == 0:
        q += letter
print(q)
```

The problem with your code is that

```
(q + x[i]) == q
```

checks if the left side is equal to the right side. Use "=" to assign values and put the identifier on the left side.